# Finding the ratios of triangle sides

Tags: solution-verification, triangles

I was asked to draw find the angles of a triangle with angles with the ratio of 10:7 and 7:3.

Multiplying all these numbers by nine gives angles of $90,63,$ and $27$. How can I now find the ratio of the sides?

This is my work: $$\frac{a}{\sin{\left(90\right)}}=\frac{b}{\sin{\left(63\right)}}=\frac{c}{\sin{\left(27\right)}}\\
 a=\frac{b}{.891}=\frac{c}{.45399}$$
Ratio of the sides: $$1:0.891 \text{ and } 0.891:0.45399$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Assuming there’s no calculation mistake in the sines, then this is fine. Try to get a consistent number of significant figures. Also, I think the ratios should be expressed as 10:7:3, and 1:0.891:0.45399. (Just some nitpicks)

Answer (score 1):

You logic is sound because one Pythagorean triple that fits your picture is
$$(589,300,661)$$
[image]
where $\sin^{-1}\big(\frac{300}{661}\big)\approx 0.471089961 r\approx 26.99146656^\circ$

Side ratios:
$$A/C= 589/661\approx 0.89107413$$
$$B/C= 300/661\approx 0.453857791$$
$$A/B=589/300\approx 1.963333333$$